# How to extract dict columns with matching keys into new dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with json objects, and inside it contains nested arrays with dicts from the json.

here is a sample:

```
    general_issue_code  government_entities
0   BUD [{'id': 200, 'name': 'Army, Dept of (Corps of Engineers)'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'SENATE'}]
1   HOU [{'id': 2, 'name': 'HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'SENATE'}]
2   HOU [{'id': 2, 'name': 'HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'SENATE'}]
3   HOU [{'id': 2, 'name': 'HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'SENATE'}]
4   HOU [{'id': 2, 'name': 'HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'SENATE'}]
```

How would I extract each name and turn it into its own column, such as:

`general_issue_code | government_entities | entity_1 | entity_2 | entity_3 | entity_4 | ... entity_n`

for the amount of unique entities in the column.

The current code that I have is:

```
test_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(x)) for x in df['government_entities']], ignore_index=True)
```

which outputs:

```
    id  name
0   200 Army, Dept of (Corps of Engineers)
1   2   HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES
2   1   SENATE
3   2   HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES
4   1   SENATE
```

But that's not quite right. I'm struggling with the keys being the same values, and I can't quite figure out how to get it to the result I need.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the goal to create kind of a sparse matrix with each unique entity in the entire dataset having it's own column? Because otherwise it will be tricky to do so with variable lengths of dicts in each row

Comment: @KeshavPotluri, yes that's correct. I might just regex it and replace all characters not matching names to leave in one column.